# Firefox Bookmarks Reference (JSON)

Tags: json, парсер, firefox

Хочу отпарсить JSON с сохраненными закладками из Firefox, но там очень много параметров, о назначении которых можно только догадываться (в частности, типы папок). А я хочу сделать нормальный импорт закладок из FF в свой софт (не костыльный, а в соответствии с документацией, которую я, к сожалению, на нашел).

Есть ли вообще такое? Или может кто разбирался в этом вопросе и написал свою инструкцию? :)

P.S. На https://developer.mozilla.org/ не нашел. Есть некоторые похожие вопросы, но по сути не то: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904522/output-firefox-json-data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox хранит закладки, историю загрузок и посещений в базе данных `SQLite`, в файле `places.sqlite`, который находится в папке `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[RANDOM.PROFILENAME]`.

В своей программе Вы можете открыть эту базу и прочесть любые интересующие данные (в том числе и перевести их в формат `JSON`). Есть небольшое разъяснение по структуре тут: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite и тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database

Схема для лучшего ознакомления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании профиля, создаётся папка с случайным набором символов, отделяющий себя точкой, в начале названия профиля: `[RANDOM.PROFILENAME]`. Чтобы узнать полный путь к профилю, Вам понадобиться ещё прочитать `INI` файл `profiles.ini` который находится в папке `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`.

В файле `profiles.ini` несколько параметров:

```
[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/s0ddpsc9.default
Default=1
```

Вас интересует именно ключ `Path`, который указывает на полный путь к конкретному профилю.

В Firefox есть ещё возможность сделать резервную копию вручную, в окне закладок, пункт: `Import and Backup > Restore...` на выходе вы получите готовый `JSON` файл.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за такой подробный ответ, но это немного не то. Дело в том, что мне нужно импортировать закладки в веб-сервис.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за такой подробный ответ (и особенно за доки), но это немного не то. Дело в том, что мне нужно импортировать закладки в веб-сервис, а скармливать SQLite-файл - не лучшее решение, тем более, что он будет использоваться в этот момент Firefox'ом (хотя данных там гораздо больше и запросом можно выбрать прям то, что нужно). Было бы идеально парсить именно JSON, что я и сделаю. :)

Comment: Все-таки решил работать именно с базой SQLite, и Ваша структура БД как раз очень кстати! :)

Answer (score 1):

bookmarks.json - это детали реализации, не стандартный формат. Поэтому у него нет описания, и он может и будет меняться с доработками Firefox.

Есть более стабильный формат bookmarks.html, для которого есть куча реализаций и даже, вроде как, документация (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но в котором не содержится все богатство информации из Firefox.

Если хотите связываться с JSON - разберитесь в текущем формате и обязательно добавьте проверки, что формат соответствует тому, что вы ожидаете.

Вот тут есть [краткое описание общей структуры](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/996823) (которая, в общем, и из примера понятна).

Истина в последней инстанции - это код, который этот файл пишет. Сейчас это [PlacesUtils.promiseBookmarksTree()](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/PlacesUtils.jsm#1729).

Comment: PS если "типы папок" - это `text/x-moz-...`, то они в том же месте кода описаны: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/PlacesUtils.jsm#209

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно!